# why can't I use my Django utilities, with django-admin

Tags: django

I installed Django with pip3 and got the up to date version but it says 'django-admin command not found'. I have python latest to, also when I tried to cd into the directory of Django admin but I failed.

Comment: did you activated your environment

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/faq/troubleshooting/#command-not-found-django-admin

Comment: I am actually a little confused about the environment I did set up a virtual environment with pip but I don't know if I have to link them some how ! id also like to say that when I directly go and open the file called Django-admin, it shows me the utilities like 'start project' but I can't use any of the utilities.